# How to substring from string in Java using regex expression

Tags: java, regex, string, extract

I want to extract a substring from "<" to "xmlns" in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XXXXX xmlns
```

then result is "XXXXX", only need 1 time. How can I do this?

Comment: do you really want to do it with regex? there are more suitable ways if you are working on an xml.

Comment: Can you search before ask? Perhaps how to make substring from string in java? Usually very general questions are already answered.

Comment: ok, I know this is wrong idea.

Comment: Regex: `<([A-Za-z:_][A-Za-z0-9:_.-]*) xmlns`, assuming tag name only uses ASCII characters, otherwise extend as defined in the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name).

Answer (score -1):

```
<[^>]+xmlns
```

Does the above regex help you? Check this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/5119047